# XML special characters using XML::XPath get_nodelist

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting XML special characters in my results when I want to original text string.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::XPath;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(ioref => \*DATA);

my $names = $xp->find('/category/event/@name');

foreach my $node ( $names->get_nodelist ) {
  print XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string( $node ) . "\n";
}

__DATA__
  <category name="a">
    <event name="cat1 > cat3" />  
    <event name="cat2" />  
    <event name="cat3" />  
    <event name="cat4" />  
    <event name="cat5" />  
  </category>
```

Here are my results:

```
 name="cat1 &gt; cat3"
 name="cat2"
 name="cat3"
 name="cat4"
 name="cat5"
```

What I want is this:

```
 name="cat1 > cat3"
 name="cat2"
 name="cat3"
 name="cat4"
 name="cat5"
```

Comment: I don't know that API but try printing `$node->getNodeValue()` instead of a string representation of the node itself.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I realized today that I hadn't followed up with this post.  For some reason, XML:Xpath was very, very slow for me.  Instead, I'm using XML:Twig to navigate my XML and eventually XHTML files.  This is much faster and gives me the results that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string` returns an XML representation of the node. Since you've got attributes in this case, you should try using `getNodeValue` to get the value:

```
print $node->getNodeValue . "\n";
```

For element and text nodes, it looks like you can use `$node->string_value`.